# What is the best CouchDB backend for Django?

Tags: django, couchdb

I am evaluating using CouchDB in my new Django-project. Is there a good database backend in Django for CouchDB? I have tried searching but the projects that turn up seems very small and/or old and I can't make out what parts are solved regarding QuerySets, Auth, Sessions etc. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check out https://github.com/stefankoegl/django-couchdb-utils for session and auth.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I did a project recently using [Couchdbkit](http://couchdbkit.org/) which worked very well - it has a Django extension which replicates a lot of the function of models and querysets. I actually wrote my own authentication backend using it, but I was able to simply modify the built-in one.

You do still need to get your head around how Couchdb works, though. I don't think you'll find anything that works as a standard database backend, allowing you to just use standard models/querysets without modification. Couchdb is non-relational and not SQL based, so the incompatibilities are too great.

Comment: Marking this as accepted answer. Couchdbkit seems to be the most mature and stable binding even though it does not really support the admin and other Django functionality but nor does any other library that I have found.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote one that is on the opposite end of the spectrum from an ORM.

http://mikeal.github.com/couchquery/

It includes the features I've needed when using Python for CouchDB and the features a few other people have needed and sent me pull requests. It's not for everyone but I find it a lot more useful than libraries that feel like an ORM.

Couchdbkit is also great, benoitc recently wrote his own http library for better speed in couchdbkit than httplib or httplib2 were providing.